# How to make TypeMock Ignore All MessageBox

Tags: c#, unit-testing, typemock

I have this annoying method which pop up a MessageBox. So when I try to test it I want to do something like this.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A test for LoadConfig exception
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void LoadConfigTest1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var target = new RFIDManager();
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[0]).WillThrow(new Exception("foo"));
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => MessageBox.Show()).IgnoreCall();

        // Act
        var result = target.LoadConfig();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }
```

This don't compile. Because

```
MessageBox.Show()
```

needs a string argument. So I want to know is it possible to specify ignore call always, no matter what is the argument ?

I don't know the exact string that will show up.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => MessageBox.Show(null)).IgnoreCall();
```

That should ignore all `MessageBox.Show()`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you need to return a value with `WillReturn(DialogResult.OK)` (or whatever you want to return) instead of `IgnoreCall`.

Comment: @vcsjones I have not used typemock much but I thought I'd post an answer since there weren't any. Why don't you post an answer and I'll delete mine (or just edit my answer) ?

Comment: `I have not used type mock much` I'm in the same boat.

Comment: This works perfectly fine. 
`Isolate.WhenCalled(() => MessageBox.Show(null)).WillReturn(DialogResult.OK);`